# i want to show webtable data in excel

Tags: java, selenium, apache-poi

i want it show all the value in excel but it not showing

driver.get("http://education-india.in/Education/Courses/?PageNumber=1");

```
    WebDriverWait wait=new WebDriverWait(driver, 30);
    List<WebElement> dropdown =wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfAllElementsLocatedBy(By.xpath("//select[@id='txtPageNumber']/option")));


    for(int k=1;k<dropdown.size()-1;k++) {
        List<WebElement> newdropdown =wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfAllElementsLocatedBy(By.xpath("//select[@id='txtPageNumber']/option")));

        List<WebElement> rows = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//table[@class='index']/tbody/tr"));
       // List<WebElement> col = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//table[@class='index']/tbody/tr[1]/th"));

        for(int i=0;i<rows.size()-1;i++){
            WebElement webRow = rows.get(i);
            List<WebElement> col = webRow.findElements(By.tagName("td"));
            XSSFRow row = sheet.createRow(i);
            for (int j=0; j<col.size(); j++) {
                WebElement webCell = col.get(j);
                String text = webCell.getText();
                Cell excelCell = row.createCell(j);
                excelCell.setCellValue(webCell.getText());
            }


        }

        newdropdown.get(k).click();

    }
```

Comment: plz guys help me ..why it showing only last page data in excel .i want all page data in excel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your code is that you are rewriting the rows every time. You are using the loop increment variable to create rows that is inside another loop. Since one page has 20 rows and you are inserting the row index of the one page from 0 to 20, it is getting overwritten by the last page.

Declare a `rowCount` variable outside the loops. And increment it every time after you create a row.

Try this:

```java
WebDriverWait wait=new WebDriverWait(driver, 30);
    List<WebElement> dropdown =wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfAllElementsLocatedBy(By.xpath("//select[@id='txtPageNumber']/option")));

    int rowCount = 0;

    for(int k=1;k<dropdown.size()-1;k++) {
        List<WebElement> newdropdown =wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfAllElementsLocatedBy(By.xpath("//select[@id='txtPageNumber']/option")));

        List<WebElement> rows = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//table[@class='index']/tbody/tr"));
       // List<WebElement> col = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//table[@class='index']/tbody/tr[1]/th"));

        for(int i=0;i<rows.size()-1;i++){
            WebElement webRow = rows.get(i);
            List<WebElement> col = webRow.findElements(By.tagName("td"));
            XSSFRow row = sheet.createRow(rowCount);
            rowCount++;
            for (int j=0; j<col.size(); j++) {
                WebElement webCell = col.get(j);
                String text = webCell.getText();
                Cell excelCell = row.createCell(j);
                excelCell.setCellValue(webCell.getText());
            }


        }

        newdropdown.get(k).click();

    }
```